Grid Of Springs In Equilibrium
Let $r: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbf{R}_{\ge 0}$ be a well-behaved map. I can construct a grid of small springs following Hooke's law, where I have vertices $v_{i,j}$ for $0 \le i,j \le n$. Two horizontally adjacent nodes $v_{i,j}$ and $v_{i,j+1}$, for $0<i<n$, are connected by a spring whose rest length is given by $r(i/n, (j + 0.5)/n)/n$. Similarly, there are springs for vertically adjacent nodes. Only the vertices at the border are fixed, while the others are free to move between the springs.
If an equilibrium of this system exists, I obtain a map from $[n+1]^2$ to $\mathbf{R}^2$ (the positions of the vertices). As I reduce the length of the springs to zero (or equivalently, increase $n$ to infinity), I wonder: is there a continuous PDE whose solution (of the shape $[0,1]^2\to\mathbf{R}^2$) I am approximating?

To first order I suspect you will get a wave equation whose equilibrium state is given by the Laplace equation.

One way to analyze it: you can start with a regular grid $(i,j)$ and then let $\Psi_{i,j}$ denote the displacement of spring $ij$ from its original gridsite then you can set up the force balance at each site to get equations for the equilibrium for $\Psi_{i,j}$. My guess (have not done the calculation) is similar to the one above with the inclusion of a source-term representing the variation of $r$ ala something like $\nabla^2\Psi \sim \nabla r$ with $\Psi = 0$ at the boundary.
